# Save Button Click results in "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I didn't use the Interface Builder to add this TableViewController am a new iOS Developer so may have missed some very simple point. When I click the cancel_Clicked button it dismisses the view properly with no error, but when I click on the save_Clicked button I get the below error.

I've searched throughout SO and haven't found a simple explanation of what could be causing this error and haven't resolved it yet. Any direction would be much appreciated.

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "Category.h"
#import "Subject.h"
#import "QuotesAppDelegate.h"

@implementation SettingsViewController

@synthesize subjects, categories, selectedSubject, selectedCategory, selectedTabs;

static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                                              target:self action:@selector(cancel_Clicked:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
                                               target:self action:@selector(save_Clicked:)];

...

- (void) cancel_Clicked:(id)sender {

    //Dismiss the controller.
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];

}

- (void) save_Clicked:(id)sender {

    for (Subject *s in selectedTabs){
        //NSLog(@"Set selected subject %@ to %ld", s.title, (long)s.active);

        //UPDATE THE ACTIVE STATUS ON THE SELECTED SUBJECTS
        [s setActiveStatus:s.active];

        //UPDATE ARRAY
        for (Subject *sub in self.subjects){

            if (sub.subject_id == s.subject_id){
                [sub setActive:s.active];
            }

        }

    }

    //RELOAD WHOLE DATABASE
    QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate populateFromDatabase];

    self.categories = [appDelegate activeCategories];
    self.subjects = [appDelegate activeSubjects];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];

}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
2015-11-13 17:19:09.763 Quotes[44015:2536500] -[NSIndexPath active]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc000000000000016
2015-11-13 17:19:09.841 Quotes[44015:2536500] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath active]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc000000000000016'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010843ef45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107eb8deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010844756d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108394eea ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108394a98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Quotes                              0x0000000105d364b8 -[SettingsViewController save_Clicked:] + 376
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010678ae91 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000106b87393 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 152
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010678ae91 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001068f64d8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001068f67a4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001068f691f -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 690
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001068f58d4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001067f8ed1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001067f9c06 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001067a92fa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000106783abf _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010836b011 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108360f3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001083603f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010835fe08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a013ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010678930d UIApplicationMain + 171
    23  Quotes                              0x0000000105cfbd9f main + 111
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001088ea92d start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: FYI - in the future make sure you symbolicate any posted crash log first and point out the exact line of code causing the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. How do you symbolicate a crash log?

Comment: Do a search. You'll find plenty of info.

Comment: I got it thanks and will do for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is with this line:

```
NSLog(@"Set selected subject %@ to %ld", s.title, (long)s.active);
```

You are trying to call `title` on `NSIndexPath`. I'm guessing that `s` is actually an `NSIndexPath` object, not a `Subject` object.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I commented this line out and updated the stack trace above. Still got the same error. But this is a good tip and I'm following this down to see if I can resolve it.

Comment: You need to look at your `selectedTabs` array. You are assuming that the array containts `Subject` objects, but they are not `Subject` objects, they are `NSIndexPath` objects. How are you populating the array?

Comment: I found the error - this was from an earlier setting where selectedTabs was not Subject but was incorrectly being set here as an indexPath        [selectedTabs addObject:indexPath]; Thanks for leading me to this solution.